# Build release failed Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to build apk with flutter. But everytime i run `flutter build apk` or `flutter build apk --release` Build always failed with an exception like this.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\naonv\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: 
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\naonv\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: 
error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     315.2s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...                       178ms
√ `android\settings_aar.gradle` created successfully.
Building plugin webview_flutter...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   37.6s
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'
Consider disabling R8 by removing 'android.enableR8=true' from your gradle.properties before publishing your app.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'webview_flutter'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s


The plugin webview_flutter could not be built due to the issue above.
```

this happend also with a flutter sample apps, maybe there's something wrong with my settings, but i don't know which i need to edit, did someone know how to solve this?

Comment: `Consider disabling R8 by removing 'android.enableR8=true' from your gradle.properties before publishing your app.
`

Comment: i deleted that code but still got the same error

Comment: open your android module separately. wait for the gradle configuration to finish. Now you see list of all the plugins. open the gradel for flutter webview_flutter and change its targeted sdk to 28. It might be less than or equal to 27.

Comment: i already use sdk 28, i tried to migrate to androidX but still got the same error, maybe it's because webview_plugin. There is 2 webview plugin for flutter, and i chose this plugin

Answer (score 0):

1. Open android folders project in android studio
2. Set app builds varients on release
3. In **android studio menu** -> **generate signed bundle** -> **generate keystore apk**